# handle input from multiple processes example in nextflow dsl2

Tags: nextflow

How do I go about defining a workflow that executes two initial processes in parallel and then handles both outputs of those processes in a third process? The simple examples I was able to find in tutorials always define sequential flows and often use stdin/stdout to transport information.

In order to illustrate what I want to achieve, here is a diagram of the DAG that I imagine:

[image: DAG]

I imagine the `.nf` file to look something like the following but cannot fill in the blanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process produceRandomX {

    output:
        x // what do I put in these places?

    """
    print $RANDOM
    """
}


process produceRandomY {

    output:
        y

    """
    print -$RANDOM
    """
}

process calculateSum {
    input:
        x
        y
    output:
        sum

    """
    print $x+$y
    """
}

process printResult {
    input:
        sum
    output:
        stdout

    """
    print $sum
    """
}

workflow {
    // syntax here is broken and just meant to illustrate what I want to achieve
    produceRandomX \
                     | calculateSum | printResult
    produceRandomY /
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextflow processes can define one or more [input](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) and [output](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) channels. The interaction between these, and ultimately the pipeline execution itself, is implicitly defined by these input and output declarations<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/basic.html#processes-and-channels)</sup>. In the following example, *produceRandomX* and *produceRandomY* could be run in parallel (assuming there are sufficient system resources available) but even if they're not, *calculateSum* will wait until it receives a complete input configuration (i.e. until it receives a value from each input channel).

```
process produceRandomX {

    output:
    stdout

    """
    echo "\$RANDOM"
    """
}

process produceRandomY {

    output:
    stdout

    """
    echo "-\$RANDOM"
    """
}

process calculateSum {

    input:
    val x
    val y

    output:
    stdout

    """
    echo \$(( $x + $y ))
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    x = produceRandomX()
    y = produceRandomY()

    sum = calculateSum( x, y )

    sum.view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run -ansi-log false main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [lonely_torvalds] DSL2 - revision: 3b752ca2cc
[07/8e1473] Submitted process > produceRandomX
[fd/d9a629] Submitted process > produceRandomY
[15/c88aac] Submitted process > calculateSum
-1331
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that depending on how many tasks are run in parallel (check `maxForks`), it could happen that the order of the output channel won't be the same as the input channel, in a way that when you do X+Y in a task of your third process, you could be summing the second element from the input channel of the first process with the first element of the input channel of the second process, for example. There are at least two ways to handle that: You use the `fair` directive or tuple with IDs + collect.

Comment: @mribeirodantas Yeah - all bets are off if they had been queue channels without some sort of key to join on. I just took "two initial processes" as two processes that produce value channels like in the example.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the calls to `x = produce...` and `y = produce...` are executed at the same time, correct? So that means the function calls are not blocked by the script inside the process definition? And also am I correct that also `sum = calculateSum(...)` is executed before `x` and `y` resolve but the `calculateSum` function blocks the script until the inputs actually resolve? In short what I am interested to know is if all 3 function calls go onto the stack together at the same time.

Comment: No. In the workflow block, lines are interpreted one after the other. `produceRandomX()` is run, then `produceRandomY()`, and so on. This is different from process instances that are implicitly parallelized and blocked or not depending on input/output definitions.

Comment: @mribeirodantas The order of the lines in the workflow block does not necessarily determine the order of execution. For example, _produceRandomY_ _could_ be run before _produceRandomX_. All three processes will be started at the same time, but _calculateSum_ will listen for a complete input configuration before it launches a new task.

Comment: @matteok Sorry for the confusion. I edited my answer to clarify things a bit better. Please also see the comments above. Hopefully these already answer your questions.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, my mistake. I didn't read your answer entirely, focused on the comment by @matteok, and thought `produceRandomX` and `produceRandomY` were regular functions, instead of processes. That's why in the second part of the answer I explained that it would work as you described above if they were processes, as they are.